# Problem with Ansible playbook quoted variable

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm trying to run the following ansible playbook. However, I am getting an error on running it.

```
---
- hosts: live
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    destination: /var/www/html/app.mytest.com/releases/{{ ansible_date_time.year }}{{ ansible_date_time.month }}{{ ansible_date_time.day }}{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}{{ ansible_date_time.second }}
  tasks:
  - git:
      repo: 'git@bitbucket:mytest/mytest.git'
      dest: "{{ destination }}"
      depth: 1
  - name: copying .env file to remote host
    copy:
      src: /root/playbooks/resources/live/.env
      dest: "{{ destination }}/"
  - name: php artisan migrate
      shell: "php {{ destination }}/artisan migrate"
  - name: php artisan package:discover
      shell: "php {{ destination }}/artisan package:discover"
  - name: npm install
      shell: "npm install"
  - name: npm run dev
      shell: "npm run dev"
  - name: php artisan queue:restart
      shell: "php {{ destination }}/artisan queue:restart"
  - name: service supervisord restart
      shell: "service supervisord restart"
  - name: php artisan queue:flush
      shell: "php {{ destination }}/artisan queue:flush"
...
```

The error i'm getting is as follows:

[image: p]

Would appreciate some help in solving this syntax error.

Comment: Try quoting the value of `vars: destination: "/var/...."` as well. Often the offending line is above the one that is reported in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation of tasks is wrong. Instead of

```
tasks:
- git:
    repo: 'git@bitbucket:mytest/mytest.git'
    dest: "{{ destination }}"
```

The correct syntax is

```
tasks:
  - git:
      repo: 'git@bitbucket:mytest/mytest.git'
      dest: "{{ destination }}"
```